# How do I connect Raspberry PI SPI pins to LED Segment via SPI?

Tags: spi

The led segment (SPI Slave) I have got has the pin names - VCC, GND, DN, CS, CLK. The raspberry pi model is 3 model B version 1.2. The segment model is [XC-3714](https://www.jaycar.com.au/8-digit-7-segment-display-module/p/XC3714).

Is my understanding correct here that this is how I need to connect the pins?
I don't want to damage the GPIO headers.

```
1) DN should be connected with MOSI of Raspberry PI i.e PIN 19.
2) CS - not sure where to connect this?
3) CLK should be connected with CLK of Raspberry PI i.e PIN 23.
4) GN should be connected with PIN 9 Raspberry pI - ground pin.
5) VCC should be connected with PIN 17 Raspberry PI - 3.3 volts.
```

Comment: CS is probably pin 18 -SPI0_CE0

Comment: This one? AliExpress MAX7219 8X8 red matrix module - US$1.5
https://fr.aliexpress.com/item/1878982769.html?spm=a2g0w.search0306.3.16.37fc4672Ypa3nk&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_0_10084_10083_10887_10307_321_453_322_454_10618_536_10065_317_537_10068_319_10059_10103_10884_10696,searchweb201603_0,ppcSwitch_0&algo_pvid=fd72c5f2-0080-40fd-bd93-d9b61a214aaa&algo_expid=fd72c5f2-0080-40fd-bd93-d9b61a214aaa-2

Comment: Details of the LED (strip?) you are using are essential.

Comment: You module uses the same chip as mine.  So the connection is also the same.

Comment: And this tutorial is good: (1) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rr_QKSyJkgM, (2) http://www.bristolwatch.com/ele2/rpi_clock_max7219.htm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses the SPI0.0 interface

- `Pin#24 GPIO08 CE0` connects to `CS`
- `pin#19 GPIO10 MOSI` connects to `DIN`
- `pin#21 GPIO09 MISO` unconnected
- `pin#23 GPIO11 CLK` connects to `CLK`
- `pin#20 GND` connects to `GN`
- `pin#17 3.3V` connects to `VCC`

Use https://github.com/rm-hull/luma.led_matrix with https://github.com/rm-hull/luma.core and https://github.com/rm-hull/luma.examples to drive it.